# Having angular js controller in tab html

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am loading html pages inside `div` using `ng-include`.
Now my problem is, I have used angular js to load html page and I want to use angular js in the loaded page also.

I tried adding controller in the child to the module which is present in the loading page and it is also not working. (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=codeCtrl&p1=not%20a)

How can I do this?

**Parent page:**
*Script:*

```
<script>
        var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
        mainApp.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function ($s, $h) {
            $s.title = "Tab1";
            $s.urls = { Tab1: "Tab1.html", Tab2: "Tab2.html", Tab3: "Tab3.html" };
            $s.currentTab = $s.urls.Tab1;
            $s.load = function (page, activeTab) {
                $s.currentTab = page;
                $s.title = activeTab;
            }
        }]);
</script>
```

*html:*

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="header">
        <button ng-class="{'active':title === 'Tab1'}" ng-click="load(urls.Tab1,'Tab1');">Tab1</button>
        <button ng-class="{'active':title === 'Tab2'}" ng-click="load(urls.Tab2,'Tab2');">Tab2</button>
        <button ng-class="{'active':title === 'Tab3'}" ng-click="load(urls.Tab3,'Tab3');">Tab3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content" ng-include="currentTab">
    </div>
</body>
```

**Child page**
*Script*

```
<script>
        mainApp.controller("codeCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($s, $h, $w) {
            $s.new = function () {
                alert('success');
            }
        }]);
</script>
```

*html:*

```
<div ng-controller="codeCtrl">
        <div class="subHeader">
            <button class="btn1" ng-click="new();">New</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your ng-app attribute references mainCtrl, rather than mainApp, for starters.

Comment: means? is there something wrong? can you explain it further?

Comment: Sure. Should have `ng-app="mainApp"`. It refers to the main angular application module. You have the `ng-controller` attribute set up correctly.

Comment: got it, it's typo, `ng-app` is on `html` tag.

Comment: I got your use case working in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hhWpDUGiEEWkR5sauh9n?p=preview). Does anything in the plunker help illuminate the issue? My guess is that the `mainApp` reference in the script tag where you declare the `codeCtrl` controller is not referring to the same `mainApp` as in the `mainCtrl` controller, but it's hard to know from the code you provided.

Comment: except for one thing, the code for `new()` is inside the loaded tab html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are loading component script in template file

You can't load scripts in angular templates,  they will be removed.

Also angular core doesn't have lazy load of components built in.
There are ways using third party modules or loading managers but for now I suggest you just include them all in main page

for more verbose error output and stack trace use the development version of angular.js ---  not `angular.min.js`

Comment: so, I can't include html which have scripts. Is there any other way?

Comment: yes...third party lazy loaders. Nothing built in as I already stated

Comment: hmm, better I change my approach only.

Comment: Need a pretty large site with many many routes and components before it is an issue. If just learning I wouldn't worry about lazy loading yet

Comment: I don't have time to experiment at this time. I try those one day.

Comment: yeah...exactly my point...focus on the learning curve of framework itself first